# return last inserted auto-increment id php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I didn't insert any value but autocrement one of the column, how could I get the last inserted id value?

I used echo `mysql_insert_id();` but I gave me '0' which isn't seem correct.

Comment: Can you show more codes? By the way, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated; use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what it returns, if you have a column type of int which is auto increment and you insert a new record, you can get the last inserted id. However if you are updating a given row at certain column field then it will not give u the last inserted id.

Comment: The last ID is only available after an `INSERT`. Incrementing a value (i.e. using `UPDATE`) will not return an ID.

Comment: ID must also be a primary key.

Comment: You can probably use the max funtion to get the max id form that table i.e. select max(id) from table.

Comment: can't you use `max()` sql function .. ?

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() use in select query

Answer (score 0):

mysql_insert_id() will work only when you insert the data into table.

Comment: it will return the next value of primary key field only

Answer (score 0):

1. Database

   CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
   id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   email VARCHAR(50),
   reg_date TIMESTAMP
   )
     last inserted ID:

---

1. Example (MySQLi Object-oriented)

---

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

---

2. Example (MySQLi Procedural)

---

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

---

3. Example (PDO)

---

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
    VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```